# How to create a directory on user login for .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a requirement, at least for now, to create a subdirectory based on a username for a .NET Core  website. Where is the best place to do this?

I tried adding in `ApplicationUser` and I am not sure how to add it correctly. What I have, which I know is completely wrong, is the following.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System.IO;


namespace BRSCRM.Models
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        private IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;
        public string HomeDir { get; set; }
        HomeDir=HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + UserName;
        string path = this.hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\uploads\\" + UserName;

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
```

I wish the documentation was better. It seems they have plenty of getting-started material out there, but when you go to try and do something that is not covered it gets pretty tough to find help.

What I am trying to do is supportfileuploading for members.

I think I am getting closer, but I get this error now:
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment'. Model bound complex   types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.CreateModel(ModelBindingContext

I cannot seem to read the IHostingEnvironment webrootpath. It is so frustrating!!

I moved my code into the Register action in file *AccountController.cs*...

This is what I have so far..

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Member");
    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
    // Add code here to create a directory...
    string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
    string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

    var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
    string path = webRootPath + "\\uploads\\" + userId;
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

I removed the code for the environment since it didn’t work anyway. I tried to just add a directory on my local system, but I discovered that I am not getting anything in the claims field. I am not sure how to get the username, email or anything else out of it. What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

The code is 1) syntactically and 2) ideologically incorrect.

1. The following code must be in some method, not in the model `class` definition

   ```
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
   ```
2. The main idea of **MVC** is to separate the model definition (**M**), business logic (controller **C**), and presentation (view **V**).  So a part of the code should be in some controller where the folder is first required (for example, `AccountController`) and called from (for example) `[HttpPost]Register` action.

   ```
    private void SetUserFolder(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment = /*getEnv()*/;
        user.HomeDir = HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + user.UserName;
        string path = this.hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\uploads\\" + UserName;

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
   ```

Comment: Ouch, I looked at adding it in the account controller but I wasn't sure how to go about it there either.. I will keep working at it.

Comment: why do you need to check if directory exists? Directory.CreateDirectory doing it internally.

Answer (score 0):

Would it meet your requirements to just check if the folder exists when the user uploads a file, then create it before saving the file if it doesn't?

As an example, if your action method (assuming MVC) is like so:

*[Upload files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads)*

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

    // Full path to file in temp location
    var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

    foreach (var formFile in files)
    {
        if (formFile.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    // Process uploaded files
    // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

    return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath});
}
```

You could simply use your own path in place of

`var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();`

and check for its existence/create it if needed before saving.

Comment: no because I need to track who is uploading the file and my process requires that the file reside in its own directory, its really quite surprising that I cannot find an example I can use for this project anywhere, not for lack of trying I have been looking for days.

Comment: Are you using MVC? you can get user properties like ID and name from the "User" property on the controller for the currently logged in user. IE: var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier); Then you can use that to build your folder path like string path = this.hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\uploads\\" + userid; and create the folder if it doesn't exist. This seems to address your requirements.

Comment: It would if I could get the implementation to work, that is where I am falling down, I tried adding it to the controller first but I cannot work out how to get it to work, so I was looking for some help.

Answer (score 0):

You may gets the current working directory of the application by using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` method.

Here is the code:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"uploads",userId);
if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
```